# Java cannot run Exec Jar using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, windows, io, executable-jar, processbuilder

I am running these line of codes to run a Test.jar which is an executable jar

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        File f = new File("path to exe jar");
        if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
           System.out.println("Valid");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }


        ProcessBuilder pb = 
                new ProcessBuilder("path to exec jar", "-jar", "Test.jar",
                        "args1","args2","args3","args4");
        pb.directory(new File("path to exec jar"));
        Process p = pb.start();

    }
```

And I keep getting this error:
File is valid though so I think this might be access issues. What do I need to add to get the access needed?

```
Valid
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "abc" (in directory "abc"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

Comment: Drop to the command line and try and use the same command, if it doesn't work from the command line, it won't work in code

Comment: Why you're using an entire Java JVM just to start another JVM is another mystery. Use a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"path to exe jar"` should be `"java"` in the constructor for `ProcessBuilder`. You can't execute a path.